# C++ unicode characters in console using printf?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, windows-console

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int pos[9];

int main() {
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c ", pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
    printf("═══╬═══╬═══");
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c "), pos[3], pos[4], pos[5];
    printf("═══╬═══╬═══");
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c "), pos[6], pos[7], pos[8];
    system("pause");
}
```

My console output:

[image: Console]

I know there are other ways of doing this, but the point was to achieve this with printf :| Any ideas?

Comment: What is your console's font set to? What is your system (ANSI) code page? Note that you aren't actually printing Unicode characters; Unicode in Windows is always the two-byte UTF-16 format (`wchar_t`). But since you're using the characters from the IBM PC character set, you may be able to get away with using narrow chars.

Comment: Problem is your output device, not the code so much.

Comment: Besides the codepage issues, you are missing the newlines at the end of each format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `printf`, and assuming you are using US-localized Windows with a console code page of 437 (run `chcp` to check), then the following corrected code will work if you save the source file in code page 437.  One way to do this is to use Notepad++ and set `Encoding->Character sets->Western European->OEM-US` on the menu.  The downside to this is your source code won't display nicely in most editors, unless they specifically support cp437, and even Notepad++ won't display it correctly on re-opening the file without setting the encoding again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char pos[9] = {'X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X'};
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c \n", pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
    printf("═══╬═══╬═══\n");
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c \n", pos[3], pos[4], pos[5]);
    printf("═══╬═══╬═══\n");
    printf(" %c ║ %c ║ %c \n", pos[6], pos[7], pos[8]);
    system("pause");    system("pause");
}
```

On Windows, since the API is natively UTF-16, a better way is to use the following code and save the file in UTF-8 w/ BOM:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char pos[9] = {'X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X'};
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L" %C ║ %C ║ %C \n", pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
    wprintf(L"═══╬═══╬═══\n");
    wprintf(L" %C ║ %C ║ %C \n", pos[3], pos[4], pos[5]);
    wprintf(L"═══╬═══╬═══\n");
    wprintf(L" %C ║ %C ║ %C \n", pos[6], pos[7], pos[8]);
    system("pause");
}
```

Output (both cases):

```
 X ║ O ║ X
═══╬═══╬═══
 O ║ X ║ O
═══╬═══╬═══
 X ║ O ║ X
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: In the first example, the program could set the console input/output codepades via `conin_cp = GetConsoleCP();` `conout_cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();` `SetConsoleCP(437);` `SetConsoleOutputCP(437)`. Then restore the original codepages at exit; the downside being that the codepages won't be restored if the program crashes or gets terminated.

Comment: Note that the first example uses the default C locale. It wouldn't work if the program called `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`, in which case the CRT will transcode (i.e. bytes -> unicode -> bytes) from the system locale ANSI codepage to the console's input codepage. The ANSI codepage (e.g. 1252) likely doesn't map these box drawing characters.